# Кодировка в Visual Studio, как включить utf-8?

Tags: visual-studio, кодировка, utf-8

Есть ли способ изменить кодировку файлов в Visual Studio на utf-8? Так, чтобы это было на постоянной основе. Нашел только один способ, но он меняет кодировку только одного файла из (к примеру) сотни уже имеющихся. Это

`File -> Advanced Save Options`
и в списке `Encoding` выбрать `UTF-8`

Comment: Увы, насколько я понял, это невозможно. Только если в отдельности обрабатывать каждый файл. Сейчас буду целенаправленно искать информацию по этому вопросу и позже обязательно выложу отчет.

Comment: у всех новых файлов кодировка UTF-8, если файлы пришлые, то только перекодировать оптом. Кто мешает написать конвертер самому? дело трех строк

Comment: @Dmitry конвертер одно дело - другое, когда это уже встроено в студию и изощряться нет необходимости) И кажется нет, не у всех новых файлов кодировка UTF-8

Comment: Студийным инструментарием вы можете перекодировать только текущий файл. Для перекодировки всех файлов вам уже написали ответ с простым конвертером как раз на 3 строки. Если не лезли в настройки студии, то у всех новых файлов кодировка UTF-8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Для автоматического сохранения в UTF-8 всех новых файлов, содержащих символы, отличные от набора ASCII, необходимо включить опцию - `Tools > Options > Environment > Documents > Save documents as Unicode when data cannot be saved in codepage`

Comment: Не помогает в Visual Studio 2017

Comment: В VisualStudio 2019 тоже не помогает.

Answer (score 5):

Взято с [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279673/save-all-files-in-visual-studio-project-as-utf-8):

раз уж вы в Visual Studio, то почему бы просто не написать код?

```
foreach (var f in new DirectoryInfo(@"...").GetFiles("*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
  string s = File.ReadAllText(f.FullName);
  File.WriteAllText (f.FullName, s, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

---

И оттуда же вариант для PowerShell:

```
Function Write-Utf8([string] $path, [string] $filter='*.*')
{
    [IO.SearchOption] $option = [IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories;
    [String[]] $files = [IO.Directory]::GetFiles((Get-Item $path).FullName, $filter, $option);
    foreach($file in $files)
    {
        "Writing $file...";
        [String]$s = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($file);
        [IO.File]::WriteAllText($file, $s, [Text.Encoding]::UTF8);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Файл -> Настройки -> Параметры -> Текстовый редактор -> Файлы -> Auto Guess Encoding -> true

Answer (score 2):

мне помогло:

`#pragma execution_character_set("utf-8")`

Answer (score 1):

Поменяй с помощью Notepad++ 
открой файл через Notepad++ --> выбери пункт кодировки --> поменяй на какую надо
Мне помогло!

Comment: Извините, вы дествительно предлагаете так обработать сотни файлов? Пожалуйста, прочтите ещё раз вопрос внимательно.

Answer (score 0):

файл => сохранить как =>нажимаешь на стрелочку указывающую вниз слева от слова сохранить и там выбираешь кодировку utf-8