# Считывание исходника *.cs на консоль

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Имеется исходник с русскими комментариями, необходимо вывести его содержимое. Шрифт Lucida, кодовая страница Console.OutputEncoding=Encoding.UTF8. Сделана попытка преобразования файла из одной кодировки в другую с помощью метода Convert(). На сколько понимаю в Visual Studio по умолчанию кодировка utf-8 (файл-дополнительно-кодировка UTF-8). На консоль выводятся вместо кириллицы другие символы (при любых манипуляциях 0,65001,866...).

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    FileStream fin=new FileStream("Program.cs", FileMode.Open);
    Console.OutputEncoding=Encoding.UTF8;

    int i;
    string s = "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Encoding utf = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    Encoding smth = Encoding.GetEncoding(65001);    //855, 866, 1251, 20866, 21866, 28595 ???                    

    do {
        i=fin.ReadByte();
        if (i!=-1) sb.Append((char)i);                  // удобно считываем файл
    } while (i!=-1);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    for (int k = 0; k<sb.Length; k++) s+=sb[k];         // в string для GetBytes()

    byte[] utfBytes = utf.GetBytes(s.ToCharArray());
    byte[] targetBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf, smth, utfBytes);     // src, dst, byte[]

    //далее в char[] и выводим string
    char[] targetChars = new char[smth.GetCharCount(targetBytes, 0, targetBytes.Length)];
    smth.GetChars(targetBytes, 0, targetBytes.Length, targetChars, 0);
    string res = new string(targetChars);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////

    Console.WriteLine(res);
}
```

Comment: Зачем так сложно? Проверьте, выводит ли ваша консоль строку `"привет"`. Если работает, выводите тупо через `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path)) Console.WriteLine(line);`.

Answer (score 0):

Работает без всяких дополнительных манипуляций в русской редакции Windows:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Можно сделать так:
        //Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
        //Главное, чтобы в Свойствах -> Шрифт консольного окна не были выбраны «Точечные шрифты».
        //
        //Или же можно сделать так:
        //Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        //Но вполне себе работает и так вот:
        Console.WriteLine("Привет, stackoverflow.ru!");
        Console.WriteLine("Сейчас напечатаем исходники, в которых есть кириллица.");
        Console.WriteLine();

        string sourcePath = @"D:\Projects\D&R\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs";
        foreach (var L in File.ReadAllLines(sourcePath))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(L);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Если у вас основной язык системы - не русский, то в комментариях есть строки с установками значений параметра `Console.OutputEncoding`. Думаю, достаточно будет установить для корректного вывода ту кодировку, в которой у вас записан файл.

По-умолчанию (так исторически сложилось), в окне консоли русскоязычных Windows установлена кодовая страница 866.

Comment: проблема в том, что не отображаются файлы, которые записаны из IDE (неважно *.txt или *.dat), поскольку они сохраняются в кодировке ASCII, что подтверждается, если их открыть в блокноте. Можно, конечно открыть блокнот-сохранить как-Unicode, тогда все норм при считывании. Получается считывать только _символьным_ i/o, а _побайтовым_ i/o не получается.

Comment: А какая у вас IDE? Пример выше я делал в VS 2015 Community, под Win 7. И Notepad++ говорит мне, что файлы исходников *.cs сохранены в UTF-8 (c BOM). Far Manager говорит про то же. 
И блокнот из Win 7 — тоже: открываю блокнотом любой файл *.cs, прекрасно вижу русские символы, нажимаю в меню "Сохранить как..." и блокнот автоматически предлагает в диалоге сохранения кодировку UTF-8.

Comment: И еще - если у вас Visual Studio сохраняет файлы не в UTF-8, то попробуйте посмотреть [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/467430/222168) про кодировку и [соответствующий ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474817/222168) на него.