# Как объяснить VisualStudio, что необходимо использовать utf-8 при сохранении и запуске файла с .py кодом?

Tags: python, visual-studio, utf-8

Впервые пытаюсь создать файл с кодом на python в VS.

на код: print("Привет")

ругается сообщением об ошибке:  File "D:..." line 1

```
print("������")
              ^
```

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid continuation byte

### Как можно данную ошибку исправить?

### (python 3.9/ VS 17.1.0)

(на латиницу не ругается, print("hello") - все окей.

Comment: ¿а кодировка файла точно utf8?

Comment: @user7860670 а как проверить? По умолчанию же должна использоваться, нет?

Comment: Оно задается при сохранении. Еще можно поставить полезное расширение https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=genrwoody.FileEncodingVS2022 - будет показывать кодировку прямо в редакторе.

Comment: Нашелся такой же вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1386203/384202

Comment: Так же можно пропробовать указать `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` в первой строке файла *.py*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ здесь
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474817/497126

"Для автоматического сохранения в UTF-8 всех новых файлов в Visual Studio, содержащих символы, отличные от набора ASCII, необходимо включить опцию - Tools > Options > Environment > Documents > Save documents as Unicode when data cannot be saved in codepage"